# Checking structural type in scala by isInstanceOf

Tags: scala, type-systems, structural-typing

I'm just checking structural type equality in scala.

I create a `foo` instance from annonymous class immediately  and a `Q` type .
I intend them to differing with method name, so that hoping them regarded as a different type structurally.

code snippet:

```
scala> val foo = new {def foo=1}
a: AnyRef{def foo: Int} = $anon$1@3885c37f

scala> type Q = {def q:Unit}
defined type alias Q

scala> foo.isInstanceOf[Q]
<console>:14: warning: a pattern match on a refinement type is unchecked
              foo.isInstanceOf[Q]
                            ^
res55: Boolean = true
```

The checking returns true.

**Q1:**
I don't understand  WHY `foo` is an instance of `Q`. 
That's nonsense. Are not they different in sense of type structure?

**Q2:**
So what is the formal way to checking the structural type?

Comment: structural types are non encoded in classes (this is also why scala uses reflection to call methods declared with "structural typing" — from Java bytecode point of view they don't exist)
so looks like Scala compiler didn't bother to create yet another class, because it would be the same as first...

Comment: also you are getting a warning for a reason

Comment: the most obvious fix is to not be wanting to check such types (think how you can encode needed information elsewhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isInstanceOf` is according to class info. In your case, you need type info:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> val foo = new {def foo=1}
foo: AnyRef{def foo: Int} = $anon$1@15ab47

scala> type Q = {def q:Unit}
defined type alias Q

scala> def getType[T : TypeTag](t: T) = implicitly[TypeTag[T]].tpe
getType: [T](t: T)(implicit evidence$1:reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])reflect.runtime.universe.Type

scala> getType(foo) =:= typeOf[Q]
res9: Boolean = false
```

Comment: thanks for information.I'm not familiar with scala reflection. Is Scala differs the "Type" to "Class" ??
                                     I found out scala reflection treats them different, I'm confused because Java's class is a type really.

Comment: `Type` in scala is more strict than `Class`. For example, `List[Int]` and `List[Double]` are different type but same class(jvm type erasure as you know).